# How do I get resource events to be contained in resourceTimeGridDay

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

Full calendar 4 + scheduler resource events are spanning down into the next timeslots.

example: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5BuS.jpg "overflowing events"

slotDuration = 15 mins
slotLabelInterval = 15 mins

I can manually change the height with css overrides, but i would like this to be dynamic so that when the window is resized it still fits.

I would like the events to fit within the expected time frames.

Comment: Normally problems like this are due to having created some custom CSS which interferes or clashes with the fullCalendar CSS, or from actively altering the fullCalendar CSS itself. Have you done either of those things? I suggest inspecting those elements with the browser's Developer Tools to see what CSS is being applied (either to the events or to the grid) and where it comes from. That's by far the most likely reason for the misalignment.

Answer (score 0):

As ADyson mentioned there was a conflicting css property being loaded by a framework, and also my css file was not being imported correctly.

Below is the css that fixed my issue:

```
.fc-unthemed .fc-time-grid-event {
    margin-top: -0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```